# Kafka Kraft Controller Leader election problem on the Rack Awareness

Tags: apache-kafka, kraft

I configured a Kafka cluster in three regions. zone1, zone2 and zone3. I have three brokers and controllers in the same node, each zone1 and zone2. The zone3 only has a single controller node for Kraft leader quorum. My problem scenario:

If the connection will be lost between zone1 and zone2, but zone3 can connect to zone1 and zone2. In this scenario, they elect a controller leader from zone3. Also, zone3 is able to connect to all zones. The new controller thinks everything okay is cluster and doesn't elect a partition leader from his own zone.

How can I set up zone3 for only election? Zone3 mustn't be a leader. When we lose the connection between zone1 and zone2, zone3 must help these clusters to elect their own leader. So both of them should be seperate cluster.

What must I do in this situation?

Comment: You need to configure the Kafka brokers in zone3 to not become leaders for any partitions

Comment: Hi @YassineCHABLI
I don't have any Kafka brokers in zone3. Only have Kafka Kraft controller node in zone3.

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behaviour.
If zone3 was elected as the controller, it decides which partition replica shall be a leader, so a single one was chosen - either zone1 or zone2.
Both of them cannot become leaders, as this cause 2 simultanious leaders within a single cluster and a splitbrain situation, which is the worst that may happen from consistency perspective.

If you wish there are become 2 leaders, then probably your usecase needs 2 separate single(or larger) node clusters, e.g.:
Cluster1 - 1 standalone broker in zone1
Cluster2 - 1 standalone broker in zone2
Zone3 - delete the host.

In any case, worth to think over on the requirements from CAP theorem perspective

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sergey.

I agree with you, two leaders cannot become on single cluster. But in this case, causing different problem. When zone3 becomes leader and says everything is okay in the cluster. In the topic partitions leaders also have zone1 and zone2. Connection is not possible between these zones. In this case apps from zone1 try to connect to zone2 and fail.

Comment: In Kafka replicas fetch data from leader. If they cannot communicate between each other, there is no good way to solve it without very dirty crutches with some proxying traffic via zone 3. Much better to setup 2 separate clusters and configure mirroring (e.g. mirrormaker) between each other